# How do I pull off a special combat action against the LQ-84i?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

I'll start by stating that I've only had a go at the game's demo so far, but I imagine this question applies to the actual game (correct me if I'm wrong).

After battling the LQ-84i and bringing it down to roughly 10% of its health, it becomes very easy to knock it around and cause it to become dizzy, at which point prompts for performing one of two special actions appear (I was playing on the PS3, so I got a prompt to press either triangle or circle).

Try as a might, however, I simply could not respond to the prompts no matter how many times I pressed either button. I tried this at a variety of distances and while in blade mode to no avail. Just how am I supposed to respond to this prompt (which I assume results in something extremely painful befalling the LQ-84i)?

Comment: Haven't played Revengeance yet...but did you try hitting *both*?

Comment: ...no I did not. That actually makes a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @Shinrai Turns out you were correct. Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: I think that can be arranged.  (Also, hey, why did I never upvote this?  Fixing that...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These prompts aren't to press *either* button - they're prompting you to press *both* buttons.